# Оптимальный вариант для динамического увеличивания блоков

Tags: java, android

Дело в том, что у меня есть несколько полей данных для одной персоны.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И если пользователь выбрал не один а больше персон, то блок должен увеличится на каждую персону.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1) *Так вот я это думал сделать на обычных лэйоутах и динамически добавлять лэйоуты для каждой персоны*

2) *Реализовать на RecyclerView*

**Вопрос:** Какой вариант правильный или я неправильно делаю? Как правильно нужно реализовать?

Comment: Что вы вкладываете в "динамического увеличивания полей" из вопроса, всё же, не ясно. И сама проблема таким образом, неясна. Попробуйте добавить конкретики и переформулировать вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Используйте `RecyclerView`
2. Передавайте в него список, содержащий объекты типа `Person`, содержащие всю инфу о персоне.
3. Создайте разметку для отдельной персоны (как на 1-ой картинке) и загружайте её как разметку эл-та `RecyclerView`.
4. В `onBindViewHolder` полям разметки назначайте данные из `Person`.

Так вы сможете отображать любое кол-во `Person` и динамически удалять/добавлять их и пользоваться всеми возможностями `RecyclerView`, включая оптимизации всякие.

Comment: Спасибо........

Comment: ЮрийСПб, еще вопросик... А если мне нужно  будет выводить у всех кроме первого без одного поля то есть без даты рождения, а у первого он будет, придется ли мне создавать отдельную разметку? или можно программно написать?

Comment: @Omuradil, можно по разному. Например две разметки и, соответственно два типа элементов, кои будут по позиции узнавать свой тип и грузить соответствующую разметку. Или да - программно. Т.е. по той же позиции можете просто у некоторых вью разметки программно через `LayoutParams` указать нулевую высоту/сделать невидимыми/вообще удалить из разметки. Я обычно просто высоту обнуляю.

Comment: Окей тогда буду обнулять, спасибо!